# How can I retain stderr from nohup?

Tags: linux

Nohup redirects stderr to stdout if it points to a terminal. But I want to retain stderr output to the terminal

Is there a way to accomplish that? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect it somewhere else, so it's not the terminal:

```
nohup bash -c 'echo OUT ; echo ERR >& 2' 2> err
```

You can redirect the stderr back to stdout instead of to a file to keep the output in the terminal, but it doesn't make much sense: `nohup` is for situations where the terminal might get lost, in which case you'll lose the stderr.

```
nohup bash -c 'echo OUT ; echo ERR >& 2' 2> >(cat)
```

Comment: i want err to go to the terminal

Comment: @IttayD: Why? What if the terminal is lost?

Comment: You can send it straight to a terminal (e.g. /dev/pts3 or /dev/ttys0), but it would be incredibly awkward (and kinda dangerous, especially for a pseudo-tty). If you lose the terminal you're in pretty big trouble. Can you elaborate a bit more on why this seems like the best way to go for context?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly or not.
you mean that you don't want to see the error in terminal?
if yes:
if you want to save the error in file:

```
nohup command 2> file.txt
```

if you don't need the errors:

```
nohup command 2> /dev/null
```

**2** means the error output of command

---

**2>** file.txt means write the error output to the file.txt

Comment: i want err to go to the terminal

Comment: @IttayD could you please write your full command, which the output isn't go to terminal